# Why does the ESP32 DevKit has a green box?

Tags: schematics, usb-device, esp32, cp2102, dev-kit

I am trying to copy the ESP32 DevKit behavior in my own PCB ([my pcb project](https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll/tree/main/PCB/schematics-v16-espinside)).
I want that the ESP is powered from USB when plugged (for programming purpose only), but then powered by my external PSU when USB is not in use (normal operation).

While studying the [DevKit schematics](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/esp32_devkitc_v4-sch.pdf), I see there is a green box and I am not sure why is that circuit marked:
[image]
Also, one of the resistors is green. Why is that?

I think it is using the page 6 of the [CP2102N datasheet](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/cp2102n-datasheet.pdf)
[image]

and then, for the USB part, the page 9
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resistor is marked green most likely because it is a component that is marked not to be mounted during manufacturing,  just like U3, as these are marked "(NC)".

The use of green box can't be guessed from the context in any way. It might be an internal marker for something, like this has changed from previous version, or this needs double checking for correctness, or this has now been fixed.